# Accessing a webServer hosted on Linux through windows

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, express, centos

I hosted a basic web Server on my Linux System with centOS and tried to access it on my windows system on the same network. But everytime it is throwing connection has timed out on my browser in windows. 
Here is the code of the js file :

```
express = require('express') app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res)  {   res.send('Hello World!') })

app.listen(4013,'0.0.0.0', function ()  {   console.log('Example app listening on port 4013!') })
```

On my windows system I am able to ping the address of linux system but while opening in browser it is not working. Any changes required or Solutions ?

Comment: What address line are you typing into your browser? Keep in mind that you need to specify port 4013 in the browser, because that's what port you configured your webapp to listen on.

Comment: @antiduh I am putting <IP of linux>:4013 in my Browser's address bar